# Mean Value of Probability Distribution Function where the Integral is equals 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

According to my studies,

> The mean $μ_X$ of a continuous random variable $X$ with probability
> density function $f_X(x)$ is $$μ_X=E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\cdot
> f_X(x)$$ but we may, and often do, restrict the integral to points
> where $f_X(x)>0$

[References](https://amsi.org.au/ESA_Senior_Years/SeniorTopic4/4e/4e_2content_4.html#:%7E:text=It%20is%20the%20weighted%20average,denoted%20by%20E(X).)

The Probability Distribution Function I'm working out is

$$f_X(x)=x(x³-x)+2$$

where $f_X(x)$ is in the interval $[-1,1]$ and with Normalizing Constant of $15/56$.

Following the reference to obtain the Mean Value:

$$μ_X=E(X)=\frac{15}{56}\int_{-1}^{+1}x[\cdot x(x³-x)+2]$$
[which is equal to 0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20x%28x%28x%C2%B3-x%29%2B2%29%20dx%2C%20x%3D-1%20to%201).

I have for sure that's not the answer. And it is said that "we may, and often do, restrict the integral to points where $f_X(x)>0$".

So here is my QUESTION which interval may I use?

$$\int_{0}^{1}x[\cdot x(x³-x)+2]$$

[which is equals to](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20x%28x%28x%C2%B3-x%29%2B2%29%20dx%2C%20x%3D-0%20to%201) $\frac{11}{12}$ once the interval must be $<1$

or

$$\int_{0}^{2}x[\cdot x(x³-x)+2]$$

[wich is equals to](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2815%2F56%29*int%20x%28x%28x%C2%B3-x%29%2B2%29%20dx%2C%20x%3D0%20to%202) $\frac{20}{7}$ once I have to respect the distance in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Thankyou!

Comment: $f_X(x)>0$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$. You do not have to restrict the integral, and the expected value is indeed 0 (try graphing the pdf).

Comment: $f_X(x)$ is even and symmetric around $x=0$, so $E(X)=0$ is correct.  Calculation not needed.

Comment: Thankyou guys! Thats such a relief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation being zero is not a problem.

You have :
$$f(x)=\dfrac{15}{56}\cdot\begin{cases}(x^4-x^2+2)&:& -1\leqslant x\leqslant 1\\[1ex]0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

The reason why we *may* restrict the integral to the the region where the *probability density function* is non-zero (called its 'support') is because, *by definition*, elsewhere the pdf contributes zero to the overall integral.

We *know* for certain that these sections will integrate to zero so we may ignore them.   That the integration over the support turns out to evaluate to zero is not a problem; we just did not *know* it would do so without investigating.

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,\mathrm d x &= \int_{-\infty}^{-1}0\,\mathrm d x+\tfrac{15}{56}\int_{-1}^{1}x\cdot(x^4-x^2+2)\,\mathrm d x+\int_{1}^\infty 0\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\tfrac{15}{56}\int_{-1}^{1}(x^5-x^3+2x)\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=0\end{align}$$

Comment: "because, by definition, elsewhere the pdf contributes zero to the overall integral" That's a great explanation. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "we may, and often do, restrict the integral to points where $f_X(x)>0$ simply means that we can safely ignore the parts where $f_X(x)=0$ in the integral. It does not mean that the expected value cannot be zero. For example, consider the pdf of a $U(0,1)$ distribution: $$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
1, & x\in [0,1]\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
In this case the expected value can be calculated as $$\int _0^1x\cdot 1\,dx=0.5$$
instead of $\int _{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)\,dx$ because $f_X(x)=0$ for any values of $x$ not in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Shouldn’t that integral be $1$, not $0.5$?

Comment: @AJY made an edit

Comment: Thanks for the example. it was a great help